# Need web-based AR solutions using markerless detection

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, artoolkit, ar.js

I am searching for solutions for web-based solutions for AR using marker-less detection i.e using plane detection or object detection. Tried using a-frame framework and three.js but they are only marker-based detection technique to render 3d object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306700/need-web-based-ar-solutions-for-plane-detection why are you asking the same question two times?

Comment: take a look at [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com) though, one of the best frameworks for markerless tracking and they had some browser-based stuff in the past (not sure about it as of now, you will have to do some research on your own)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Didn't know about the browser-based stuff of Wikitude. Will check it out. :)

Comment: depending on what you want, you could go for Unity3D -> WebGL too, since there are a lot of AR Plugins for Unity. Might be a bit tricky though

Comment: You need to unroll a SLAM implementation. 8th wall provides one: https://docs.8thwall.com/web/#introduction

Comment: @CommodoreYournero can you suggest a plugin for Unity3D -> WebGL -> AR? I could only find a plugin for VR.

Comment: @DivyaChhipani i have no real experience with this, but i would suspect that you can simply build any ar-application for webgl too with unity. If you are not familiar with unity, i would suggest searching for another solution, good luck anyways